# Flot not displaying timestamps/dates correctly

Tags: javascript, flot

Flot graph do not show date/hour correctly. In x-axis there are values of unix timestamps.

data:

```
 [[1365712202000,61.39],[1365712510000,60.89],[1365712817000,0]]
```

flot configs:

```
    $.plot(plotarea , [
        {
            label: "Value",
            data: dataLine,
            color: "#FF8848",
            lines: { show: true, steps: false },
            points: { show: true },
            grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
            xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%d/%H/%M" }
        }
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong.  `xaxis` and `grid` are not series options but plot options.  Try:

```
$.plot($('#placeholder') ,[{
        label: "Value",
        data: dataLine,
        color: "#FF8848",
        lines: { show: true, steps: false },
        points: { show: true }            
    }],
    {
       grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
       xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%d/%H/%M" }
    }
);
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/1694/).